# Linguistic approach to noun-verb transition

Tags: functions

I have noticed that many nouns can be used as verbs and vice versa. Why is that so with English? What is the linguistic approach to this? Is that because English is an analytic language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually just put an 'ing' at the end. eg:

> ski-skiing       hurt-hurting   throw-throwing

If the noun consists of only one syllable and ends with a consonant then you double the last letter eg:

> cut-cutting

In case the last character is an 'e' then you just leave that away and add the 'ing' eg:

> ride-riding